# Should I remove logging to my final release project?

Tags: java, maven, logging, jar, log4j2

I am developing a Java application that takes and analyzes user input using both the Scanner and Console classes. I am also using log4j2 for logging. Since Eclipse does not work well with the Console class, I have to create a jar file using the Maven-Assembly-Plugin to add the dependencies of my project and then test it from the command line. I was wondering if I should leave my logging code when I release the final jar file.

Thanks!

Comment: Huh? Why would you want to remove logging? What if the application fails? Don't you want to read why?

Comment: you probably want to have different logging levels and change the level not remove the logging as a all

Comment: First, when I run my program from the command line like `java -cp "ads-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" com.mijecu25.ads.Driver` I do not see where the log files are. Second, I have never release a project to the public, so I am not sure if the creation of many log files will consume people's hard drive

Comment: Logging is very important and is getting more important when other people using your software. As mentioned, publish your application with a logging level of warn or error. This will only produce log entries when an error or warning appears. Which is exceptable for the users hard drive space ;)

Comment: I agree that logging is very important and I can change the level for the final product. However, right now that I am testing the project using the command above, I do not see any log files. Should I create another questions for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the people who commented above said, logging is very important and should not be removed from a project. Increase the logging level for the final product.